# Copy result of SQL Server query to Excel

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to figure out a way to copy the result of a SQL Server query to Excel. I know that with PostgreSQL, you can execute the following command:

```
COPY (SELECT id, summary, description FROM table) TO 'C:/test/table.xls';
```

to achieve the desired result. What is the equivalent method in SQL Server?

And I want to run it as a query statement since I would like to automate this process by running the query with a batch file as a scheduled task.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1202/export-data-from-sql-server-to-excel/

Comment: Something like this one : SELECT id, summary, description FROM table INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file.xls'

Comment: it says incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'

Comment: i got this error from following the link:Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, just use BCP (Bulk Copy Program) to do the job like this:

bcp "select * from [databasename].[dbo].[tablename]" queryout  "c:\test\table.csv"  -c -t"," -r"\n" -S servername -T

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO
OPENROWSET (
  'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;Database=C:\test\table.xls;',
  [Sheet1$]
) 
SELECT id, summary, description FROM table
```

Some limitation

- You must create empty excel file first.
- You must add column names in first row appropriate with inserted data.

Comment: it says OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' has not been registered

Comment: @user974047 You must install [Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Comment: ive ran the installation file and it still gave me that error in MSSQL

Comment: Do you install it on your sql server?

Comment: i clicked through the default options during the installation process

Comment: @user974047 OK, but do you install it on machine with sql server instance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
mysql -b -e "$MY_QUERY" > my_data.csv
and see this Q for ref and more detail
[Convert mysql query results to CSV (with copy/paste)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066897/convert-mysql-query-results-to-csv-with-copy-paste)